# Spring RestTemplate Follow Redirect 302

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to understand the logic for REST call redirects through Spring Boot.
Basically, I'm trying RestTemplate(Spring Boot) to do a POST login call.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate ....

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> valueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
mvm.add("username", "login");
mvm.add("password", "password");

...........

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriDWLogin, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

The response entity is giving 302 status response, but I want to follow this request to get the response body.

I am thinking RestTemplate would automatically follows redirects - 302 status code, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Pino those comments could work for different perspectives,
For me, 1. I am not switching the protocols(http --> https or https -> http)
2. I don't want to switch from existing implementationof RestTemplate

Comment: @Shreekant *2. I don't want to switch from existing implementationof RestTemplate* The default implemenation seems not to work, so you have to switch. What's the problem?